# A trivial fact about factorisations of functions of two variables: how to prove it?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, summation, real-numbers, products

Let $s<t \in [0,T]$. Let $g_1,g_2$ and $f_i, \tilde f_i, \, i=0,\ldots, n$, be real continuous functions on $[0,T]$ that are never $0$ such that

$$g_1(s) g_2(t) = \sum_{i=0}^n f_i(s) \tilde f_i(t).$$

I want to prove the trivial fact that either all $f_i(s)$ are multiples of $g_1(s)$, i.e $g_1(s)=\lambda_i f_i(s)$ where $\lambda_i \in \mathbb R_0$, or all $\tilde f_i(t)$ are multiples of $g_2(t)$.

It seems so simple, yet I cannot produce a rigorous proof. It seems a proof by contradiction would be suited for this, yet I do not see the contradiction.

Comment: Presumably, you want it for all $s,t,$ not just one pair $s,t?$

Comment: Why should this be true?  Why, for instance, couldn't $f_1(s)=0$ for some $s$ without $g_1(s)=0$?  For instance, suppose $f_0=g_1$ and $\overline f_0=g_2$ but all the other $f_i, \overline f_j$ identically zero.

Comment: Yeah, you will want $f_i=\lambda_i g_1,$ to allow $f_i$ to be zero. Or you could add that $f_i,\tilde f_i$ are not identically zero.

Comment: How does $\mathbb R_0$ differ from $\mathbb R?$

Comment: Is there a reason you call it trivial? Like, someone to.d you it was trivial? If so, that changes how people approach the problem. But if you are only guessing it is trivial, you should probably avoid saying so, because it might seem obvious to you, but it may be like the Jordan Curve Theorem, or may not even be true, if you have no reason to know it is true.

Comment: @lulu Thank you for your comment, I forgot a piece in the statement, it is now correct.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $\mathbb R_0$ is all the reals but $0$. Trivial means "of little importance or value".

Comment: Mathematicians uses “trivial” as “easy.” @W.Volante

Comment: This can be rewritten as: If $$\sum_{i=0}^n f_i(s)\tilde f_i(t)=1$$ for all $s<t$ then either all $f_i$ or all $\tilde f_i$ are constant.

Comment: If we think of $f,\tilde f:[0,T]\to\mathbb R^{n+1}$ then this is saying, if $f(s)\cdot \tilde f(t)=1$ for $s<t,$ where $\cdot$ is the vector dot product. You want to conclude that one of $f,\tilde f$ is a constant function.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews How is my statement and yours equivalent ? Particularly, how does yours imply mine ?

Comment: Divide both sides by $g_1(s)g_2(t),$ since the functions are nowhere zero. Then define $h_i=f_i/g_1,\tilde h_i=\tilde f_i/g_2.$ Then you reduce to my version.

Comment: But my version is not true. We can make $\tilde f$ constant on $[0,T_1]$ and $f$ constant on $[T_1,T].$ Then we can construct with care such functions which are no constant. So your statement is false.

Comment: It might be true if you remove the condition $s<t.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true.

We will find a counter-example when $g_1$ and $g_2$ are both constant functions equal to $1,$ and $n=1, T=2.$

Let $$f(s)=\begin{cases}(2,-1)&0\leq s<1\\\left(1+s,-s\right)&1\leq s\leq 2\end{cases}$$

$$\tilde f(t)=\begin{cases}(1,1)&1\leq t\leq 2\\\left(\frac32-\frac{t}2,2-t\right)&0\leq t<1\end{cases}$$

Now if $s<t$ then:

- Case: $0\leq s<t<\frac{1}{2},$ then $f(s)\cdot \tilde f(t)=(2,-1)\cdot \left(\frac32-\frac{t}2,2-t\right) =1.$
- Case: $\frac12\leq s<t\leq 1,$ then $f(s)\cdot \tilde f(t)=(1+s,-s)\cdot (1,1)=1.$
- Case: $0\leq s<\frac12\leq t\leq1.$ Then $f(s)\cdot \tilde f(t)=(2,-1)\cdot(1,1)=1.$

You can write out the four functions $f_i,\tilde f_i$ as case statements to ensure they are never zero, and none are constant functions.

---

It is not even true if you make the equality true for all $s,t.$

If $U_t$ is a continuous set of planes, all containing the same common line in $\mathbb R^3,$ and none containing $0,$ you can define $f$ to be any continuous function restricted to the line, and define $\tilde f(t)$ to be a vector $u$ such that $U_t=\{v\mid u\cdot v=1\}.$

For example, the common line being $(1+3\alpha,1+\alpha,\alpha),$ the planes are $ax+by+cz=1$ with $a+b=1$ and $2a+2+c=1.$ So for $t\in [0,1],$ we get the equation for $U_t$ is $(3-t)x+(t-2)y+(2t-7)z=1$ and $$f(s)=(4+3s,2+s,1+s)\\\tilde f(t)=(3-t,t-2,2t-7)$$

Or $$1=(4+3s)(3-t)+(2+s)(t-2)+(1+s)(2t-7)$$
For all $s,t.$ With $s,t\in[0,1],$ all of $4+3s,2+s,1+s,3-t,t-2,2t-7$ are non-zero.

So, give any $g_1,g_2$ and $T=1,$ you can define:

$$\begin{align} f_0(s)&=(3s+4)g_1(s),\\f_1(s)&=(2+s)g_1(s),\\f_2(s)&=(1+s)g_1(s),\\\tilde f_0(t)&=(3-t) g_2(t)\\ \tilde f_1(t)&=(t-2) g_2(t)\\ \tilde f_2(t)&= (2t-7)g_2(t)
\end{align} $$

---

A little more work gives us strictly positive example:

$$36=(10+s)(1+t)+(2-s)(7-2t)+(2+s)(6-3t)$$
All the terms are positive when $s,t\in[0,1].$

Comment: Interesting, I wonder if this still holds if we impose that the functions cannot be constant.

Comment: No, we just multiply this answer by $g_1(s)g_2(t)$ to get an example for any $g_1,g_2,$ as I noted in my comments to the question. @W.Volante

Comment: @W.Volante Found a counterexample which works for all pairs, $s,t.$

Comment: More generally, for $a,b,c,d$ we get a set of solutions: $$((2a+b)+s)((c-d)+t)+(b-s)(c-t)+(a+s)(d-2t)=(2c-d)(a+b).$$ If $c>d>2T, b>T,a>0$ the terms are positive for $s,t\in [0,T].$